# Too few arguments to function 0 passed and exactly 1 expected with DI container

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I trying to use [Php league container](https://container.thephpleague.com/3.x/) to inject service in my AdminController:

```
class App {

 public function __construct() {
    $container = new Container;
    $container->add(CompanyCreateService::class)
            ->addArgument(CompanySqlRepository::class);
    $container->add(CompanySqlRepository::class)
            ->addArgument(DbConnection::class)
            ->addArgument(Hydrator::class);
    $container->add(DbConnection::class);
    $container->add(Hydrator::class);        
    $container->add(AdminController::class)
            ->addArgument($container->get(CompanyCreateService::class));                
    $container->get(AdminController::class);
         $this->actionIndex();
}

public function actionIndex() {
    $controller = new AdminController();     
}
```

}

Admincontroller using CompanyCreateService as injection

```
class AdminController {

public $companyService;

public function __construct(CompanyServiceInterface $companyService) {
    $this->companyService = $companyService;
    $this->actionCreate();         
}

public function actionCreate() {
    $dto = ...
    $this->companyService->createCompany($dto);    
}
```

It saves dto into database and it's normal, but i getting an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Site\Company\Application\AdminController::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in ... AdminController.php

My classes:

class CompanySqlRepository implements CompanyRepositoryInterface {

private $hydrator;    
private $db;

public function __construct(DbConnection $db, Hydrator $hydrator) {       
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->hydrator = $hydrator;
}


class CompanyCreateService implements CompanyServiceInterface {

private $repository;
public function __construct(CompanyRepositoryInterface $repository) {

    $this->repository = $repository;
}

public function createCompany($dto): void {       
    $this->repository->add($dto);
}
```

How to use Di container without errors? And why it saves into database despite on error?

Comment: have you ever found a solution? I opened an issue on Github because after spending hours on debugging this I couldn't find the cause. :( https://github.com/thephpleague/container/issues/189